# remove digits numbers in imacros without touch the phrase

Tags: imacros

I have iMacros which is take the data from csv file to post it to a website, 
It runs good but
In my csv file have 4 columns 
1 title 2 desc 3 price 4 phone

& column number 3 contain digits numbers only and the issue is some time contain like that 00 or 00000 or 000 or 0 or 1111111 or 222222222 which is wrong price
so i want to replace it with "" but in the same time i don't want to print "PRICE" phrase

so output it looks like this:

subject: HELLO WORLD
desc bla bla bla bla contact me 22212123 
PRICE 00

and here my code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=NAME:subject CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAR("'{{!COL3}}'.replace(/^0/gi,""
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!COL4}}'.replace(/\+95/gi,"")")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=ID:vB_Editor_001_textarea
CONTENT=<SP><SP>desc<SP>{{!COL2}}<SP>contact<SP>me{{!VAR2}}<BR>PRICE<SP>{{!VAR1}}<BR>[/CENTER]
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=ID:vB_Editor_001_save
```

and i expect output like that if the price contain like that wrong numbers

subject: HELLO WORLD
desc bla bla bla bla contact me 22212123

but if not contain will print it looks like this:

subject: HELLO WORLD
desc bla bla bla bla contact me 22212123 
PRICE 120

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play this code sample:

```
SET price 00000
' your second line may look like this
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{price}}'.replace(/^0+/,"")")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```